# Origin of coordinate system, TGA file in C

Tags: c, coordinates, tga

In my program I am writing geometrical shapes at different positions. This is what the header looks like:

```c
    TGAHeader header = {
        .id_length = 0,
        .color_map_type = 0,
        .image_type = 2,
        .color_map = 0,
        .x_origin = 0,
        .y_origin = 0,
        .width = w, 
        .height = h, 
        .depth = 32,
        .descriptor = 0,
    };
```

The problem is that the origin of coordinate system is in the bottom left corner and I need it to be in the top left. I've tried multiple things to change the origin but none of it works.

I've tried changing the values to

```
.x_origin = 0,
.y_origin = 1
```

or

```
.x_origin = 0,
.y_origin = {0,1}
```

I don't really know how it works. I was hoping that the picture would be drawn from top to bottom.
Do you have any idea what might be the problem? Thanks for any help.

Comment: https://github.com/processing/processing/issues/1682

Comment: BMP files are also stored upside down.  When I was new to image processing I was sure  they were just messing with me.  Many years later, I still think so, lol.

Comment: @gregspears More perverse than that, they are doubly upside-down (i.e. the right way up) if the height is negative. Gotta love Microsoft!